# Ideal web application framework for newcomers and whether it is better to use Java or PHP based framework?

Tags: php, web-development, java

My primary question is whether a Java based web application framework is better or a PHP based one and why?

Moreover, if I were just starting web development then what would be some ideal frameworks to start with, considering I may want to make a full CMS out of it later? I am not looking for a 'best', rather some good recommendations as I understand that CodeIgnitor has not got a long way to go from here : http://heybigname.com/2012/05/06/why-codeigniter-is-dead/

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh, the "ideal framework and which-language-better" question. You can really write a whole book about available frameworks, their aims, pros and cons, language differences in general and in detail, industry support, costs during and after development, projects that use x or y; you can ask lots of questions about your own skills with PHP or JAVA or x, project requirements, your funding, infrastructure, team, ... Please be way more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: Project funding: 0. Knowledge :: Java: good, PHP: ok.
I am looking for a general overview. I know it wont have a perfect answer ever, but I am not looking for a one way or other approach.

Comment: You will find more information on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=web+framework+java+php

Answer (score 1):

if you google for "best java framework" and "best php framework" you'll find lots of sites and blogs that give very helpful and detailed opinions to the topic.

You'll get no better answer here and no greater list. I really recommend you take the time and actually install and try one or two of each Java and PHP framework. Thats just two days of fun, experiments and learning. Take the one that feels best.

If you really want a one page answer list I recommend you switch to http://stackoverflow.com and search for the phrases above. Most of the questions will be closed with the statement "closed as not constructive", but you'll get some answers nevertheless. Stackoverflow is the better forum for these questions.